# Dual boot windows and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, uefi

[image]
I'm trying to do a dual boot for both windows and ubuntu on my laptop. I've done this thing before but now it's not working.
I tried installing windows first, doing the rufus thins, but when I got to the installation part of ubuntu, it said "continue with UEFI mode" and it's when it failed.
So I did a full installation of ubuntu and replaced windows, but I need to work on some apps there. So I tried the GParted thing, and it's all greyed out.
Can someone please help?
**Sorry for the long intro. Here's the screenshot.**

Comment: You have erased Windows. And the little lock icons say partitions are mounted, so you need to use live installer if you want to modify partitions and may still have to do a swapoff to unmount swap as live installer usually mounts it. You have MBR partitions which is for the 35 year old BIOS boot configuration. You can use that or reinstall both Windows & Ubuntu in UEFI mode (if UEFI hardware) which will convert (erase) drive to gpt partitioning. How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs, but both Windows & Ubuntu should be in same boot mode.

Comment: Installing both in UEFI didn't work. Ubuntu crashed at certain point. And yeah I remember converting the partitions to MBR. So... I'm THAT new to Ubuntu but still pretty new, how to do that?

Comment: This is the comprehensive guide for UEFI installs: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: which version of ubuntu are you installing? there was a bug in the grub script that adds the efi firmware option to the grub menu.

Comment: MichaelBay, I'm on Ubuntu not windows. I installed ubuntu first.

Comment: ravery, It's 16.04

Comment: So basically what do I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restore windows 7 after installing ubuntu using windows factory reset disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486637/how-to-restore-windows-7-after-installing-ubuntu-using-windows-factory-reset-dis) and [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)