# Windows 11, Ubuntu and Bitlocker

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, windows, encryption

I want to clean-install **Win11 over Ubuntu** 20.04.
I originally installed Ubuntu over Win10 back in the day.

*My problem:*
The Win11 installer tells me there is **no partition** in any of my drives that I could install Win11 to.

I have 2 hard disks (1 TB and 128 GB). Ubuntu is installed on the 1TB one and most of the 128 GB disk is encrypted by Bitlocker (from previously using Win10). I don't recall the Bitlocker recovery key, so I can't decrypt the partition.

Is there any way I can install Win11? Thank you!!!
I am not a tech pro, so please be gentle :)

Comment: I suppose you could use an Ubuntu LiveUSB to reformat your Ubuntu disk to remove your Linux partitions (so the Windows installer would no longer balk at it). You could also complain to Microsoft about a installer that apparently cannot detect common Linux partitions, leaving non-tech-pros confused and frustrated. Were I paying for the software, I would expect a compatible, well-tested, and helpful installer.

Comment: Boot from live media and use gparted to remove all partitions. Boot from windows install media and install to your totally empty hard drive.

Comment: Even better: Use GParted to create a new partition table (Device menu), choose GPT. This automatically remove all partitions leaving a blank GPT drive, the ideal condition for *any* OS installer. But this isn't a Ubuntu question, this is entirely a Windows question.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still confused. Would it help if I simply formatted my 1TB hard drive on which Ubuntu is installed to GPT and then restart and complete the installation with my bootable USB? I need sth as simple as that. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restore windows 7 after installing ubuntu using windows factory reset disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486637/how-to-restore-windows-7-after-installing-ubuntu-using-windows-factory-reset-dis)